# Is there a parallel file archiver (like tar)?

Tags: performance, tar, archive

Is there something out there for parallel archiving of files?

Tar is great, but I don't use tape archives, and it's more important to me that the archiving happens quickly (with compression like bzip2) since I have smp.

Comment: tar is for more than just tapes. The name originally came from tape, but these days I see it being used mostly for when you want to put things into a single file for redistribution while maintaining directory structure information with optional compression.

Comment: there's quite a few parallel compression tools benchmarked here http://vbtechsupport.com/1614/ however have yet to find a parallel version of tar

Comment: None of the answer provided (including the accepted one) handle *directories*, so far as I can tell - they handle *files*. I only see `zip` as being able to handle directories :|

Comment: Actually, what we usually do is to package *directories* in `tar` archives, and then compress the package using a file compressor (like `gzip`, `pigz`, etc.). You can do it in two steps, but also *in one single step*, since they can work on data streams from standard input/output. The results are very similar to `zip`, but more versatile.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I think you are looking for pbzip2:

> PBZIP2 is a parallel implementation of
>   the bzip2 block-sorting file
>   compressor that uses pthreads and
>   achieves near-linear speedup on SMP
>   machines.

Have a look at the [project homepage](https://launchpad.net/pbzip2/) or check your favorite package repository.

Comment: You can also try `pigz` and `pxz` for parallel implementations of `gzip` and `xz`. You can compress using a command like `tar c dir | pigz -c > dir.tar.gz` and decompress using `pigz -cd dir.tar.gz | tar xf -`.

Comment: Commands today would be `tar -cf dir.tar.gz -I pigz dir` and `tar -xf dir.tar.gz -I pigz`. Also `xz` is threaded: use `XZ_OPT=-T0 tar -cJf dir.tar.gz dir` and `XZ_OPT=-T0 tar -xJf dir.tar.gz`.

Comment: @Rich This question is not specific to any platform, meaning it applies to BSD and GNU alike. Your "today" version (which was just as usable 7 years earlier) only applies to GNU versions as `-I` means "read filenames from file" on BSD versions of tar (such as on macOS) and the `XZ_OPT` env var is unknown to the bsd version.

Comment: Fair enough. I was writing specifically about GNU and not Unix.

Answer (score 27):

The OP asked about parallel archiving, not parallel compression.

If the source material is coming from a filesystem where different directories/files might be on different disks, or even a single fast disk that exceeds the input speed of the compression tool(s), then could indeed be beneficial to have multiple streams of input going into the compression layers.

The meaningful question becomes, what does the output from a parallel archive look like? It's no longer just a single file descriptor / `stdout`, but a file descriptor per thread.

An example of this so far is the parallel dump mode of Postgresql `pg_dump`, wherein it dumps to a directory, with threads working over the set of tables to back up (work queue w/ multiple threads consuming the queue).

I'm not sure of any actual parallel archivers that are mainstream. There was a hack for Solaris Tar for use on ZFS: http://www.maier-komor.de/mtwrite.html

There are some dedicated backup tools that successfully run multiple threads, but lots more that just split the workload by directory at a high level.

Answer (score 24):

[7zip](http://p7zip.sourceforge.net/) can run on multiple threads when given the `-mmt` flag, but only when compressing into 7z-archives, which offer great compression but are generally slower than zip to create archives. Do something like this:

```
7z a -mmt foo.7z /opt/myhugefile.dat
```

Comment: 7z is a nice archiver, with good support for controlling the tradeoffs between compression ratio and comp/decomp time, random access vs. better compression, and stuff like that.  However, it doesn't store nearly as much metadata as tar, you lose owner/permissions.

Comment: It looks like this options is on by default - at least I've got no performance increase with it and 7z' output has line about amount of cores of my CPU in both cases.

Answer (score 16):

```
tar --use-compress-program=pigz  ....
```

replace `pigz` with your favorite parallel compression program.  The reason to use `tar` is because it can store the owner, group, permissions.  That metadata is often useful (e.g., restoring a dir tree in a complex system).

Comment: tar -c --use-compress-program=pigz -f myDirectory.tar.gz myDirectory/

Comment: All options, AFAIK, for tar can be used normally along with the `-I` option, which is the same as `--use-compress-program`.  So, e.g. `tar cvzf /some/dir/yournewarchive.tar.gz /directory/tobecompressed --exclude="/directo...."` can be applied to the multi-threaded option using `pigz` as `tar -I pigz -cvf /some/dir/yournewarchive.tar.gz /directory/tobecompressed --exclude="/directo..."`.  This is the best, most appropriate answer, IMHO.  Thanks @uDude ! :)

Answer (score 11):

[pigz](http://www.zlib.net/pigz/) is a parallel implementation of gzip, but can only really use multiple processors for compression, not decompression.

Comment: Did some experiments, and `pigz` actually seems to be able to use multiple threads **also** when decompressing. Try comparing the output of `time tar xf dir.tar.gz` and of `time pigz -cd dir.tar.gz | tar xf -` (on my 4-core CPU it takes a bit less than half the time).

Comment: @gerlos Using `time` on a pipeline will only time the first command.  From the [`pigz` documentation](http://zlib.net/pigz/pigz.pdf): "Decompression can't be parallelized, at least not without specially prepared deflate streams for that purpose. As a result, pigz uses a single thread (the main thread) for decompression, but will create three other threads for reading, writing, and check calculation, which can speed up decompression under some circumstances."

Comment: There's also [pixz](https://github.com/vasi/pixz).

Answer (score 8):

`tar` is simply an archive format that is very good at exactly duplicating the files and preserving the directory tree and the original file attributes. TAR is very good for making backups, because everything is preserved. I use `pbzip2` to compress the tar archives I use for system backups with very good results.

this command should do the trick.

```
tar -cpS "infile" | pbzip2 > "outfile"
```

`pbzip2` can be replaced with a different compression utility, but be warned, LZMA compression (like pxz) uses a TON of RAM when compressing/decompressing large files (I tried to run 8 threads with 8GB of RAM, and pxz started swapping to disk).

Answer (score 5):

Another contender is [`lbzip2`](http://lbzip2.org/). It's quite similar to pbzip2

Answer (score 5):

As far as compression is considered, `xz` since about version 5.2 supports parallel compression via the `-T` option.

Comment: If you want to use this in combination with tar just call export XZ_DEFAULTS="-T 0" before.